# Binding a Simple Viewmodel with Single Record

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs6

I created [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/utq) showing what I want to do.

Basically, I configured a `Store` that loads only a single record (it reality it will be the currently signed in user). However, I can't seem to bind anything to that store properly. How can I get that `{u.name}` to output properly?

Here is the code:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name']
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        new Ext.Component({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            viewModel: {
                stores: {
                    u: {
                        proxy: {
                          type: 'ajax',
                          url: 'user.json'
                        },

                        model: 'User',

                        autoLoad: true
                    }
                }
            },

            bind: 'Test name: {u.name}'
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  `bind: 'Test name: {u.data.items.0.name}'`

**UPD:**
As an explanation to this - **u** is an object with its properties, so trying to bind to **u.name** will actually bind to the **name** property of the store. Wile the store has no name property it will always be null. Store's received data is placed in **data** property. Items property contains a raw array of received data and so on.

Comment: If you are not sure about the answer then please post it as a comment not as an answer if possible.

Comment: @ρss I'm pretty sure in my answer.

Comment: Then please provide some explanation to your answer regarding why should it work, it helps unintelligent users like me :P and also it shall also cause your answer to get upvotes!

Comment: I hope that's better ? ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle you're using a store while it looks like you need just a single record.

Using [`links`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewModel-cfg-links) instead of `stores` should work better, like:

```
links: {
    u: {
        type: 'User',
        id: 1
    }
}
```

Working example based on your code: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uuh

Comment: What will happen when user with id=2 will login? How to use links more dynamically?

Comment: @CD.. -- Aren't you assuming I would know the `id` of the user who is logged in? This is how the all the docs recommend it is done but it always assumes you would know the `id` somehow

Comment: @yorlin: you can use `linkTo` for setting the link dynamically: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewModel-method-linkTo

Comment: @CD.. Is it possible to set a dynamic url using links as it is done for stores, i.e. proxy: { url: '/base_url/{id}'} ?